# Dishwasher Spits water

Tags: leak, dishwasher

I have a Maytag dishwasher model # MDB4709AWW4.

It spits water out the front left corner only after the pause after the pre-wash cycle. The water is clean and is always about the same amount.

Comment: What exactly is the  question ?

Comment: So do you get enough water for the wash? If adequate, why worry. We need more information to digest your problem.

Comment: Check the seal on the door- see if it is cracked.